# How can I read each line from a file into one variable for the last field, and another variable for the other fields?

Tags: bash, text-processing

How can I read a line from a file into two variables: one variable for the last field, and the the other variable for the other fields?

For example, I have a file:

```
hello world! 10s
It is a good day. 4m
...
```

I would like to read each line into two variables: one variable contains the time interval at the end of the line, and the other variable contains the fields before it. I was wondering how to do it; this is as far as I have gotten:

```
while read line 
do
    ...  # split $line into $message and $interval
    myprogram "$message" "$interval"
done < "$inputfile"
```

Comment: Will the interval ever contain white space?

Comment: Thanks. The time interval will be used as argument to `sleep`. If `sleep` accepts an argument with a space within it, then yes; otherwise, no.

Comment: Obligatory https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller Could you tell me how I should rewrite my while loop? I have looked at the link

Comment: It's apparent that reading into variables is not your final destination; there might be other/better ways to accomplish your goal, if we knew what it was.

Comment: @JeffSchaller It is any executable `myprogram` which expects two arguments.

Comment: Why use the shell; have myprogram read the text file directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the interval contains no whitespace this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

input=/path/to/input

while read -r line; do
    message=${line% *}
    interval=${line##* }
    echo "$message"
    sleep "$interval"
done < "$input"
```

`${line% *}`  Will strip everything after the last space character

`${line##* }` Will strip everything before the last space character